# Pandas groupby indexing before and after transform

Tags: group-by, dataframe, transform, pandas

My motivation for this problem is that I'm trying to deduplicate records. Some fields can just be dropped, but I would like the sum of other fields.
For the following dataframe,

```
In [48]: rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
         df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar'] * 2 + ['baz', 'qux'],
                                        'B': rand.randn(6),
                                        'C': rand.randint(0, 20, 6),
         })
In [49]: df.sort('A', inplace=1)
Out[49]:      A         B   C
         1  bar -0.611756  18
         3  bar -1.072969  10
         4  baz  0.865408  14
         2  foo -0.528172  11
         0  foo  1.624345   5
         5  qux -2.301539  18
```

I would like to deduplicate records with the same `A` value, but keep the sum of `B` (and maybe `C` in some cases). I think groupby's transform should do what I want:

```
In [50]: df.groupby('A')[['B']].transform(sum)
Out[50]:           B
         1 -1.684725
         3 -1.684725
         4  0.865408
         2  1.096174
         0  1.096174
         5 -2.301539
```

But for some reason, I noticed it doesn't give me what I want when I index at the end:

```
In [51]: df.groupby('A').transform(sum)[['B']]
Out[51]:           B
         1 -0.611756
         3 -1.072969
         4  0.865408
         2 -0.528172
         0  1.624345
         5 -2.301539
```

Why is there a difference? Also, when I try to transform on 2 columns, it doesn't do what I expected:

```
In [52]: df.groupby('A')[['B', 'C']].transform(sum) #same result as df.groupby('A').transform(sum)[['B', 'C']]
Out[52]:           B   C
         1 -0.611756  18
         3 -1.072969  10
         4  0.865408  14
         2 -0.528172  11
         0  1.624345   5
         5 -2.301539  18
```

I don't mind the discrepancy in this situation, but in the application I'm working on, it's actually doing the opposite, but I can't find an example that reproduces it (i.e., `df.groupby('A').transform(sum)[['B', 'C']]` gives me what I want, but the faster `df.groupby('A')[['B', 'C']].transform(sum)` doesn't).

Comment: My guess is it has to do with the dimension of what's being transformed.  In your first example you're selecting one column to sum over.  In the second, you're summing the entire group and then selecting the B column.  The transform mechanic is a bit mysterious, agreed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it lies in the `transform` method. If you look at the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation), it says that `transform` returns an object that is indexed the same (same size) as the one being grouped. In fact your

```
df.groupby('A').transform(sum)[['B']]
```

doesn't do any summation at all.

If all you need is the sum, this:

```
df.groupby('A')[['B']].sum()
```

or this:

```
df.groupby('A').sum()[['B']]
```

should do and they produce the same result.

Comment: I want it to be in the same shape as the original dataframe. `In [50]` gives me the output I want, I'm just wondering why `51` doesn't as well.

Comment: Can you please give reproducible example, we could help you MUCH MORE easily.

Comment: I don't understand, are you not able to reproduce my code above? My main question is about the discrepancy between input `50` and `51` above, which I expected to yield the same output. Is there something I should make more clear?